# image on top of button android

Tags: android, android-layout, button, imageview

Is it possible to add an image(view) on top of a button (which as a background image)?

I'm porting an iOS app to Android and it wasn't a problem on iOS, but I'm wondering if it is the right approach on Android because of layouts.

Edit :

To clarify, check this screen shot :

http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/062/Purple/v4/7c/4b/cd/7c4bcd53-ba55-94d7-a26c-ce1bfe040003/mza_2736801523527387264.320x480-75.jpg

I need to do the bottom left button "carte" (card in french)

I need :

- a button with a background image
- an image displayed on top of the button which is loaded from internet (a card , there is a lot of different and news cards are added daily, in the screnshot it s "MIDI PASS" )
- a text localised on the button , so I cant use Imagebutton class.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want an Image to act as a button

Comment: can't imagebutton 'll work for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not quite clear what you want to achieve, but the following may be helpful for you:

- Use an [`ImageButton`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)
- Set the Image as the background of the button either in XML (using [`android:background`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3abackground)) or in code (using [`setBackgroundResource`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29))

**Update**:

Looking at your updated requirements, it would be better to use a [custom component](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat unclear but from what i understood, following may work for you:

```
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imgButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_image"
            android:src="@drawable/top_image"/>
```

Hope it will be helpful.

UPDATE:
If Your background is common, then you can set the bitmap using following code:

```
((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgButton)).setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Here, you will need to get the bitmap of the card image in bmp variable.

Comment: look at this screenshot : http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/062/Purple/v4/7c/4b/cd/7c4bcd53-ba55-94d7-a26c-ce1bfe040003/mza_2736801523527387264.320x480-75.jpg , the button at bottom left is what I need. it s a button displayed only in some situation, to indicate a card is required, and there is a lot of different cards, so I cant use image resources. I had to change the card image in code.

Comment: and is background common for all?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) and implement the onClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

Use an ImageButton then....

set your android:src="@drawable/foreground Image" 
 set your android:background="@drawable/background Image"

So if you wanted a an apple for the background image and a 3-d word "apple" for your foreground image.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

First, you create a selector for the button in the res/drawable/ folder (let's call it selector_button.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_resource_for_button_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_resource_for_button_pressed"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_resource_for_button_normal" />
</selector>
```

Here you can define as and `android:drawable` not just `@drawable`'s, but `@color`'s or `@layout`'s, too. If you want a more complex layout, you should define one with the background image of the button and another image on top of it using a `RelativeLayout` for example.

In order to do this, you have to have `image_resource_for_button_pressed.png` (for pressed and focused state) and `image_resource_for_button_normal.png` (for normal state) in your res/drawable/ folder.

After that, you create a button, like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/aButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_button"
    android:text="Hardcoded string" />
```

This approach helps you maintain code readability, since you just extracted the changing of the image resource into an .xml file.